# Variance of predicted value in linear regression model

Tags: regression, variance, linear-regression

I am working on a question whereby I have calculated the linear regression model

$$Y_i = -20.57 + 1.7446x_i + \epsilon_i ,$$

and have been given the data that $x_i$ = 85.  From this, I have calculated that the predicted value is 127.721, but have now been asked what the variance of this estimate is. I have calculated the residual variance $\sigma = 1.95$, but am not sure where to go from here?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: I guess that variance of the estimate if just the variance of $\epsilon_i$ in thie case. How did you find the residual variance here?

Comment: In this case they gave us the sum of squares of the estimated residuals and divided by (n-p), where n was the number of samples and p is the number of regression coefficients.